# Script to find dead website/domain

Tags: powershell, nslookup

I am working on a powershell script to find websites which are either not running on our server or pointing to another server. I am fetching all website names from a file and using it to find only those websites which are not running on our server. I'm trying to use below script but getting an error.

As always, and help or advice would be much appreciated.

```
$servers = get-content "path_to_the_file"
foreach ($server in $servers) {
$addresses = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($server)
foreach($a in $addresses) {
"{0},{1}" -f $server, $a.IPAddressToString
 }
}
```

Below is the error I am getting:

```
Exception calling "GetHostAddresses" with "1" argument(s): "No such host is known" At      
C:\test1.ps1:3 char:50 + $addresses = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses <<<< ($server) + 
CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
DotNetMethodException
```

Comment: Don't hold us in suspense: what's the error?

Comment: Below is the error i am getting   Exception calling "GetHostAddresses" with "1" argument(s): "No such host is known" At C:\test1.ps1:3 char:50 + $addresses = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses <<<< ($server) + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: Works fine at my end. At which `$server` value is this failing at your end?

Answer (score 2):

Just trap the exception:

```
try {
    $addresses = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($server);
}
catch {
    $addresses = [IPAddress]'0.0.0.0';
}
```

Comment: Thank you Bacon. I am still learning powershell.I have modified my script but output is not as desired. The script is as below. The out put should be only those domain which is not running on our ser <br/> $servers = get-content "C:\test1.txt"
foreach ($server in $servers) {
try
{
  $addresses = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($server)
}
catch{}

  foreach($a in $addresses) {
try
{
    $d="{0},{1}" -f $server, $a.IPAddressToString
}

catch{}

}
If ($d -match '184.154.53.165')
{
#Write-Host "#"
#write-host "Domain name is "
#$d


}
else {

#Write-Host ""
#write-host "Domain name is "
$d
}

}