# Powershell - Get server name and IP from text list

Tags: powershell, csv

I am using the following suggestion provided in this link:
[Experts-Exchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/Powershell/Q_27722701.html)

I am trying to take a server (host name) list and save the host name and IP address in a .csv file.

Using the following Powershell code, I do see the host name but the same IP address, for every server, in the results pane.

```
$servers = get-content "C:\TEMP\servers.txt"
$serversAndIps = "C:\TEMP\List_of_servers_with_ips.csv"


$results =@()
foreach ($server in $servers) {
  $results =@()
    $result = "" | Select ServerName , ipaddress
    $result.ipaddress = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($server)
  foreach($a in $addresses) {
    "{0},{1}" -f $server, $a.IPAddressToString
  }
    $result.servername = $server
    $results += $result
}
$results | export-csv -NoTypeInformation $serversandips
```

When I open the .csv file, I get this:

```
"ServerName","ipaddress"
"Server_name_1","System.Net.IPAddress[]"
```

If I run this PowerShell script, I can get the host name and the correct IP address in the results pane.  I just need to know how to transfer the results to a .csv file.

```
$servers = get-content "C:\TEMP\servers.txt"
foreach ($server in $servers) {
  $addresses = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($server)
  foreach($a in $addresses) {
    "{0},{1}" -f $server, $a.IPAddressToString
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try taking that $results =@() out of the inside of the loop.

Comment: @mjolinor I took that out and now I get all of the host names, but I still get "Server_Name_1","System.Net.IPAddress[]"

Comment: You're storing the `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($server)
` object in an array. If you do a Get-Member, you'll see that your array is storing an object of type System.Net.IPAddress. You will probably need to do something like this instead: $result.ipaddress = ([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($server)).IPAddressToString

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like some simple typos at work.

- $result was being reset inside the in the loop
- $addresses inside the loop wasn't assigned.
- $result.ipaddress was not assigned to $a.IPAddressToString for the output object.

Try this:

```
$servers = get-content "X:\servers.txt"
$serversAndIps ="X:\test.csv"

$results = @()
foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    $result = "" | Select ServerName , ipaddress
    $result.ipaddress = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($server)
    $addresses = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($server)

    foreach($a in $addresses) 
    {
        "{0},{1}" -f $server, $a.IPAddressToString
        $result.ipaddress = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($server)
    }

    $result.servername = $server
    $result.ipaddress = $a.IPAddressToString
    $results += $result
}

$results | export-csv -NoTypeInformation $serversandips
```

Comment: We all have to start somewhere. Best of luck.

Comment: If the IP is not reachable then script throws exception on lines 8,15 and 25, so they should be wrapped in try-catch like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27573389/911419)